# Removing transparency from color

Tags: c#, colors, background, textbox

Currently I am using this code to convert my RGB string to a color to set as a the background for a Text Box.

```
 ColorConverter colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
 colorTextBox1.BackColor = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(displayColor);
```

But I get this error when I run this code.
when the value of `displayColor  = "#16776960"`.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Control does not support transparent background colors.
```

Any idea on how I can take out transparency from the color?

All I want it to do is make the background of the text box that color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controls do not support semi-transparent colors, and your hex string has `16` at the beginning, which is the alpha component. To apply the color to a control, you will need to strip the alpha from it.

```
ColorConverter colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
Color color = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(displayColor);
color = Color.FromARGB(255, color.R, color.G, color.B);
colorTextBox1.BackColor = color;
```

You can also simply remove the alpha from the string if it is more than 7 characters long (6 color chars and 1 #)

```
string hex = "#16776960";
if (hex.Length > 7)
   hex = hex.Remove(1,2);
```

Comment: Can I just remove the 16 from the string. If so can I just remove the second and third character from the string each time.

Comment: Yeah, you can just remove the first 2 characters if it is more than 6. Also, fixed the read only issue. Forgot how `System.Drawing` colors worked compared to XNA colors.

Comment: One more question how do I keep the color some what similar.

Comment: The colors are off for example blue is purple